# Forward or Move

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Are these valid usage of move and forward? 
Are f3 and f4 the same? 
Is it dangerous to do so? 
Thank you!

```
#include <utility>
class A {};
A f1() {
  A a;
  return a;   // Move constructor is called
}
A f2(A&& a) {
  return a;   // Copy constructor is called, which is what I try to avoid.
}
A f3(A&& a) {
  return std::forward<A&&>(a); // Move constructor is called
}
A f4(A&& a) {
  return std::move(a); // Move constructor is called
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::forward` exists because of a quirk in how `&&` works under type deduction.

Under type deduction, the `T` in `T&&` will bind to one of 3 possibilities.  If being deduced from an lvalue `int&`, `T` will bind to `int&`.  Then `int& &&` is just a `int&`.  If being deduced from an lvalue `int const&`, `T` will bind to `int const&`, and `int const& &&` is `int const&`.  If being deduced from an rvalue `int` of some kind, `T` will bind to `int`, and `int&&` is `int&&`.

`std::forward` is a utility function to reverse that map.  The three pertinent signatures of `std::forward<>` are: `T& std::forward<T&>(T&)` or `T const& std::forward<T const&>(T const&)` or `T&& std::forward<T>(T&&)`

All of this ends up being exceedingly useful when doing the technique known as "perfect forwarding", where you use `T&&t` in a type deduction context, then `std::forward<T>(t)` to pass on the "same type" as was deduced from to another call.

Note that there are a few simplifying lies above.  There are is also the possibility of `T const&&` which is pretty obscure type-wise, as an example.  I probably glossed over some details of how the type deduction works, and the terms `rvalue` and `lvalue` don't fully reflect the full 5-fold (or is it 6?) different kinds of variable values in C++11.

Answer (score 2):

- Use `std::forward` with a *universal reference*, i.e. a `template <typename T> ... T&&`.
- Use `std::move` with an *rvalue reference* (like your `A&&`).

So both `f1` and `f4` are plausible solutions. They do different things, so you have to decide which one you want.

Do not use `f2` or `f3`.

Answer (score 1):

For your example, they will do the same thing, but it is idiomatic to use `std::move`

```
A f(A&& a) {
  // use std::move(a)
}
```

A slightly different case is with function templates

```
template<typename A>
A f(A&& a) {
   // use std::forward<A>(a)
}
```

The difference is that the second version can receive both lvalues and rvalues (Scott Meyers named them "[**universal references**](http://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload111.pdf)"), whereas the first version can only receive rvalues.