# What's difference between forward and move in the constructor of class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I read a lot about it but still can't get. What's difference between these two variants:

```
template <typename val_t>
class fact_t: public exp_t<val_t> {
    val_t m_value;
public:
    fact_t(val_t &&value) : m_value{std::forward<val_t>(value)} {}
};

template <typename val_t>
class fact_t: public exp_t<val_t> {
    val_t m_value;
public:
    fact_t(val_t &&value) : m_value{std::move(value)} {}
};
```

Can someone show an example when one variant will fail but another will work still?

I tried to use the first variant the next way:

```
std::string str = "str";
fact_t<std::string> f(str);
```

But it leads to an error of compile time. Although as I understood from other topics and *cppreference* that `str` is **lvalue** and `std::forward` allows to use it. Where am I missing?

**P.S.** I'm sorry if is a stupid question but I really can't get.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671749/whats-the-difference-between-stdmove-and-stdforward. Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/16014527

Comment: @KerrekSB I read this topic too

Comment: @KerrekSB, but when I tried to write a something like this `std::string x = "str"; fact_t<std::string> f(x);`, it fails in both variants. Although as I understood it's **lvalue** and must work with `forward`. What is wrong?

Comment: @Jans I read this topic already. I've updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `val_t` is not an lvalue reference type, then `value` in constructor is an rvalue reference, and `std::forward` is equivalent to `std::move`.

If `val_t` is an lvalue reference, then so is `value`. `std::forward` then returns an lvalue reference and the code compiles. `std::move` returns an rvalue reference, which cannot be bound to `m_value` (which is an lvalue reference), and compiler reports an error.

[Demo](https://rextester.com/BRUH67054)

The reason `fact_t<std::string> f(str);` fails to compile is it's trying to pass an lvalue to a parameter that expects an rvalue.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! I got I declared a parameter wrong